# how to use complex library in a header file?

Tags: c++, header-files, complex-numbers

I have written a piece of code that uses complex library. I have put the definition of my function in a header file and in the main.cpp i have defined the complex number "I" as you can see in my codes below.
But when i want to compile this code i receive errors.

I think the function in the header file can not use complex library.
How can i fix this problem?

Thanks.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include <complex>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;
typedef complex<double> cmp;
cmp I(0.0,1.0);

int main()
{
cout << function(5.0) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef header
#define header

double function(double x)
{
return 5*exp(I*x).real();
}

#endif
```

Comment: when you say you receive errors, you should also say what errors they are.

Comment: You wrote `I have written a piece of code that uses complex.h header file` But your code does not show `#include "complex.h"` or `#include <complex.h>`. Am I right you have compilation errors?

Comment: I made a mistake i should have written complex library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `I` is not defined when your header file is parsed.  You would need to move the definition of `I` before the `#include "header.h"`.

Comment: Better to just include it in the header file where it is needed.

Comment: @EdS.: Wrong header your thinking of.

Comment: @EdS. - good point, though if any other code has to include this header we'd have to try something else.  Maybe something like `extern cmp I;` would be the best plan.

Answer (score 3):

Because `I` is defined after the `header` include, your main.cpp essentially becomes this:

```
double function(double x)
{
    return 5*exp(I*x).real();
}

using namespace std;
typedef complex<double> cmp;
cmp I(0.0,1.0);
```

The compiler parses your function, and throws an error because it doesn't know what `I` is (yet).

You should include any constants that functions rely upon before the function, like this in your header file:

```
#ifndef header
#define header

#include <complex>

typedef complex<double> cmp;
cmp I(0.0,1.0);

double function(double x)
{
    return 5*exp(I*x).real();
}

#endif
```

Comment: I added #include <iostream> and "using namespace std;" before typedef in header file then your code worked.

Answer (score 2):

You should include the library header file in your header(`header.h`) which uses the library symbols.

```
#include <complex>
```

It is always better to include all the dependencies of an file within itself rather than depending on them to be included otherwise. Maybe your `header.h` gets included somewhere the library symbol name dependency does not get resolved indirectly through other includes.

**EDIT:**

On a side note I am not sure why you included the definition of the function in the header file itself. You should, change the header to only have the declaration:

**header.h**

```
#ifndef header
#define header

#include <complex> 

typedef std::complex<double> cmp;
extern cmp I;

double function(double x);

#endif
```

Add another source file which defines the function

**header.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"    


double function(double x)
{
    return 5*exp(I*x).real();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include <complex>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;
cmp I(0.0,1.0);

int main()
{
   cout << function(5.0) << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: He does. This is not an answer.

Comment: @Linuxios: If he does, I don't see where he does so and I don't know how you know he does.

Comment: @Linuxios: No, he doesn't, read more carefully.  He has a function definition in his header.  This is the best answer.

Comment: @EdS.: And he includes `<complex>` in his `.cpp` file. This is NOT his problem.

Comment: @Als: I is not a library symbol, but his *own* symbol.

Comment: Thank you
I used your codes, But it did not work. Did it worked for you?

Comment: @Linuxios: `I` is declared *after* the header file which uses it is included.  That certainly *is* the problem.

Comment: @yashar: *did not work*, does not really help in knowing anything.What error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

Change your header.h to contain this:

```
double function( std::complex<double> I, double x)
```

Change your main.cpp so it contains this:

```
cout << function(I, 5.0) << endl ;
```

You problem was because in your `header.h` you used variable I which was not visible.

Comment: Thank you.
It worked for me, but what about the situation in which the type of the function should be complex instead of double.

Comment: Are you asking about the second parameter or result?
Anyway, it can be like that: `std::complex<double> function( std::complex<double> I, std::complex<double> x)`